# Swig - binding a method returning a reference to a pointer of a director class

Tags: python, c++, swig

Ok, the title is a bit long, but I couldn't figure out a shorter one :) So let me explain.

I have a C++ codebase where we have some container classes. Those classes have access methods returning items by reference or const reference. Then in another part of the codebase, I have containers of heap allocated `object`'s, which are using the director feature.

And I can't figure out how to specialize our container classes for `object`: For all the container methods returning references to items (in this case a reference to an `object`'s pointer), Swig generates a wrapper code which fails to compile due to an invalid dynamic_cast (basically it tries to cast `object **` into `Swig::Director *`)

I managed to reproduce the issue with the following code.

Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

template< typename T >
class Vector
{

public:

    inline Vector(void)
        : m_Data(nullptr)
        , m_Size(0)
    {
    }

    inline ~Vector(void)
    {
        delete [] m_Data;
    }

    inline void add(const T & item)
    {
        T * data = new T [m_Size + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Size; ++i)
        {
            data[i] = std::move(m_Data[i]);
        }
        delete [] m_Data;
        m_Data = data;
        m_Data[m_Size++] = item;
    }

    inline const T& item(int index) const
    {
        return m_Data[index];
    }

    inline int count(void) const
    {
        return m_Size;
    }

private:

    T * m_Data;
    int m_Size;

};

class Foo
{

public:

    Foo(void) = default;
    virtual ~Foo(void) = default;

    virtual const char * method(void) const
    {
        return "Foo::method";
    }

};

class Cache
{

public:

    static void add(Foo * item = nullptr)
    {
        m_Cache.add(item == nullptr ? new Foo() : item);
    }

    static const Vector< Foo * > & get(void)
    {
        return m_Cache;
    }

    static Foo * get(int index)
    {
        return m_Cache.item(index);
    }

private:

    static Vector< Foo * > m_Cache;

};

Vector< Foo * > Cache::m_Cache;

#endif // TEST_H
```

core.i

```
%module(directors="1") core

// we want to be able to inherit Foo in Python
%feature("director") Foo;

// generate wrappers
%include "Test.h"

// specialize Vector for Foo
%template(FooVector) Vector<Foo*>;

// when compiling the wrapper code, include those
%{
#include "Test.h"
%}
```

If you generate the Python module (`swig.exe -python -c++ core.i`) it works fine, but the generated `core_wrap.cxx` file fails to build because the generated wrapper code for `Vector::item` contains an invalid dynamic_cast from `Foo **` to `Swig::Director *`

The offending line is (where result is of type `Foo **`)

```
  director = SWIG_DIRECTOR_CAST(result);
```

And if I manually fix it like this:

```
  director = SWIG_DIRECTOR_CAST(*result);
```

Then the module compiles correctly, and everything works fine.

So basically my question is: is this a bug in Swig ? Am I doing things wrong ? Is there a workaround to tell Swig to correctly dereference my `Foo **` result before casting to `Swig::Director *` ?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I have encountered some similar situations, where I have `#ifndef SWIG_VERSION` to skip certain function. Have you tried just wrapping `Vector` of say `int` to see whether it is related to `directors` or a general cast issue. Another thing - why are you using directors, I see no Python class implementing `Foo`.

Comment: Wrapping `Vector` of types which are not using the `director` feature works fine (the invalid `dynamic_cast` is in the generated part related to this feature only) So specializing `Vector` for `int` works fine. And you see no Python class implementing `Foo` because `%feature(director)` is meant to be used when the class implementing `Foo` is defined in Python (well, in my case at least, that's what I need) And I didn't provide an example Python script which uses the example module, because the module doesn't even compile so it's not really relevant.

Comment: If you skip the use of native RTTI by adding the compile option `-DSWIG_DIRECTOR_NORTTI` your example compiles..

Comment: You're a life saver ! It compiles, and my example use-case works as intended ! I feel a bit dumb for not having thought of trying to define this macro (I remember seeing it in the generated wrapper code and wondering what its use was) If you want to add this as a proper answer, I can then accept it (maybe it will help other people in the future :)

Comment: I will do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem.

In some situations, using the director feature and native RTTI leads to code, which does not compile out of the box, e.g. when using `distutils` from Python.

A solution, which works for your example is to define `SWIG_DIRECTOR_NORTTI` when compiling the code, e.g. for the GNU compiler add `-DSWIG_DIRECTOR_NORTTI` to the `CXXFLAGS`